# Determining processing order for (almost) in-place computation

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation, in-place

I have an `i` channel image, `image`. I also have `f` filters, `filters`, that can be applied to a channel. I want to generate an `o` channel image, `output`, by selectively applying filters to the channels of the image. I currently have this defined with two lists, `image_idx` and `filter_idx`, so that processing is done as

```
for j in xrange(o) :
    output[j] = filter[filter_idx[j]](image[image_idx[j]])
```

Because the images can be pretty large, I may want to do this processing in-place. This may require processing the channels in a specific order, to avoid writing over data that you will need later. I am currently checking if such an order existes, and computing it, with the following function:

```
def in_place_sequence(indices) :
    """
    Figure out a processing sequence for in-place computation.
    """
    indices = [j for j in indices]
    positions = set(range(len(indices)))
    processing_order = []
    change = True
    while change and len(positions) :
        change = False
        for j in list(positions) :
            val = indices[j]
            if (j not in indices) or (indices.count(val) == 1 and val == j) :
                indices[j] = None
                positions.remove(j)
                processing_order.append(j)
                change = True
    if len(positions) :
        return None
    return processing_order
```

For example:

```
In [21]: in_place_sequence([4, 0, 3, 0, 4])
Out[21]: [1, 2, 3, 0, 4]
```

And a possible processing order to avoid overwriting would be:

```
img[0] -> img[1]
img[3] -> img[2]
img[0] -> img[3]
img[4] -> img[0]
img[4] -> img[4]
```

This is implemented something like:

```
for j in in_place_sequence(image_idx) :
    image[j] = filter[filter_idx[j]](image[image_idx[j]])
```

I am starting to hint that, when it fails to find a sequence, is because `image_idx` defines a closed loop permutation. For instance:

```
In [29]: in_place_sequence([2, 0, 3, 1])
```

returns `None`, but it could still be done in-place with minimal storage of 1 channel:

```
img[0] -> temp
img[2] -> img[0]
img[3] -> img[2]
img[1] -> img[3]
temp   -> img[1]
```

I am having trouble though in figuring out a way to implement this automatically. I think thee way to go would be to keep my current algorithm, and if it fails to exhaust `positions`, figure out the closed loops and do something like the above for each of them. I have the impression, though, that I may be reinventing the wheel here. So before diving into coding that, I thought I'd ask: what is the best way of determining the processing order to minimize intermediate storage?

---

**EDIT** On Sam Mussmann's encouragement, I have gone ahead and figured out the remaining cycles. My code now looks like this:

```
def in_place_sequence(indices) :
    """
    Figures out a processing sequence for in-place computation.

    Parameters
    ----------
     indices : array-like
         The positions that the inputs will take in the output after
         processing.

    Returns
    -------
     processing_order : list
         The order in which output should be computed to avoid overwriting
         data needed for a later computation.

     cycles : list of lists
         A list of cycles present in `indices`, that will require a one
         element intermediate storage to compute in place.

    Notes
    -----
    If not doing the opearation in-place, if `in_` is a sequence of elements
    to process with a function `f`, then `indices` would be used as follows to
    create the output `out`:

        >>> out = []
        >>> for idx in indices :
        ...     out.append(f(in_[idx]))

    so that `out[j] = f(in_[indices[j]])`.

    If the operation is to be done in-place, `in_place_sequence` could be used
    as follows:

        >>> sequence, cycles = in_place_sequence(indices)
        >>> for j, idx in enumerate(sequence) :
        ...     in_[j] = f(in_[idx])
        >>> for cycle in cycles :
        ...     temp = in_[cycle[0]]            
        ...     for to, from_ in zip(cycle, cycle[1:]) :
        ...         in_[to] = f(in_[from_])
        ...     in_[cycle[-1]] = f(temp)
    """
    indices = [j for j in indices]
    print indices
    positions = set(range(len(indices)))
    processing_order = []
    change = True
    while change and positions :
        change = False
        for j in list(positions) :
            val = indices[j]
            if (j not in indices) or (indices.count(val) == 1 and val == j) :
                indices[j] = None
                positions.remove(j)
                processing_order.append(j)
                change = True
    cycles = []
    while positions :
        idx = positions.pop()
        start = indices.index(idx)
        cycle = [start]
        while idx != start :
            cycle.append(idx)
            idx = indices[idx]
            positions.remove(idx)
        cycles.append(cycle)
    return processing_order, cycles
```

Comment: "Because the images can be pretty large, ..." -- How large are they really?  Computers these days have *lots* of memory ...

Comment: @mgilson Running out of memory is part of my daily routine. Images these days also tend to have lots of pixels, e.g. a [6 ink, 60" wide printer](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF05a/18972-18972-3328061-215168-3328080-5053950.html?dnr=1), printing at 600dpi, needs 129.6Mbytes **per inch** of plot, so it can get out hand pretty fast. Even with some fancy in-place algorithm I will have to process my image in chunks, but hopefully this way I can make chunks twice as large.

Comment: Fair enough :).  Just wanted to make sure you weren't "optimizing" prematurely.

Comment: @Jaime I'm not seeing why you need a temporary in your second example,  but maybe I misunderstood or skipped something. In that example, the image has four channels: 0, 1, 2, and 3. None of them are used more than once. Therefore, all you need is `img[i] -> img[i]` for all `i` channels.

Comment: @mmgp That doesn't work, though, because (for example) the 0th output channel is created using some filter applied to the 2nd input channel.  You could create output channels as you suggest, but then you'll either have to move the channels around (requiring a temp channel) or use some indirection to rename the channels (probably slower).

Comment: @SamMussmann I'm not seeing the problem you mention, and I'm not seeing where in the question it is said that the order `[2, 0, 3, 1]` (second example) gives any different result than `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. So, if we reorder the second example to `[0, 1, 2, 3]`, there is no need to create output channels (I'm not suggesting that anywhere in that comment), there is no need to move channels around either, there is no need to "use some indirection to rename the channels either". The filter is applied to channel 0, and the result is stored in channel 0, and so on.

Comment: I think we're going to need @Jaime to weigh in here -- I expect the order of the output channels is important because whatever is consuming the image (the printer?) expects them in a certain order, but I'm inferring this more than explicitly reading it.

Comment: @SamMussmann I may not explicitly say that the order is important, but it is strongly implied by the code included in the question. You have understood very well what my problem is, and your answer and comments are being very helpful. It is true though that I could spare the intermediate storage by doing each of the channels in a cycle in their own place and keeping an indexing list. Right now it seems like it will complicate things further down the line, so I would like to avoid it, but I will need to give it some more thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your method is as good as you'll get.

Think of a representation of your `indices` list as a directed graph, where each channel is a node, and an edge (`u`, `v`) represents that output channel `v` depends on input channel `u`.

As written, your solution finds a node that has no outbound edges, removes this node and its incoming edge, and repeats until can't remove any more nodes.  If there are no more nodes left, you're done -- if there are nodes left, you're stuck.

In our graph representation, being stuck means that there is a cycle.  Adding a temporary channel let's us "split" a node and break the cycle.

At this point, though, we might want to get smart.  Is there any node that we could split that would break more than one cycle?  The answer, unfortunately, is no.  Each node has only one inbound edge because each output channel `v` can only depend on one input channel.  In order for a node to be part of multiple cycles, it (or some other node) would have to have two inbound edges.

So, we can break each cycle by adding a temporary channel, and adding a temporary channel can only break one cycle.

Furthermore, when all you have left is cycles, splitting any node will break one of the cycles.  So you don't need any fancy heuristics.  Just run the code you have now until it's done -- if there are still `positions` left, add a temporary channel and run your code again.

Comment: I didn't bother reading the code included, but it is pretty clear (to me) that the problem is just a graph coloring, or more specifically a register allocation, preceded by a simple instruction scheduling by topological sort. Said that, I'm not sure if you tried avoiding these by mentioning "fancy heuristics", or whether do you believe register allocation by graph coloring is overkill for the problem. Is that the case ? (Just checking whether we are thinking about the same things.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is orthogonal to register allocation.  The OP needs to find an order to create output channels from input channels such that no input channel is overwritten before all the output channels that are created using it have been created.  If the dependency graph were a DAG, then topological sort (basically what the OP's code does) would work.  But the dependence graph is not necessarily acyclical, so I show how to break cycles and why this is as efficient as you can get.

Comment: Your second phrase is pretty much what a register allocation would do efficiently. The topological sort is used just to give an initial input.

Comment: From my understanding of register allocation, I'm not seeing the structural similarity between this problem and register allocation.  That could very well be me.  Even if register allocation is applicable, I still think that the constraint on the number of inbound edges means that no algorithm is going to use fewer temp channels than the naive algorithm I give.

Comment: @SamMussmann I have gone ahead and figured out the cycles. I have added my code as an edit at the end of the question. Thanks for your help!